# Android RestFul API call for post method

Tags: android, rest

I am having a doubt on how can I post a data where my REST end point URL is like below:

```
http://my.domain.com/Upload/{ID}/{IMAGE_CONTENT_AS_BYTE_ARRAY}
```

I need to send the the Image content as byte array string to this end point method. But Since the charater length can go beyond 2000 character length, I may not be able to send the the IMAGE if its huge since everything goes as part of URL string. How can I put the data of `IMAGE_CONTENT_AS_BYTE_ARRAY` .
    Also I don't have any key for this so that I can put it in namevalue pair.Please suggest!

Comment: Did you implementt this already? It's unclear to me what you have. Do you have it working for very small images already?

Comment: `to send the the Image content as byte array string`. Well what is that exactly? Pleae elaborate. `{IMAGE_CONTENT_AS_BYTE_ARRAY}`. That does not tell you to use a string though.

Comment: These is the placeholder my webservice team had given to send the byte array of the image in the REST API

Comment: Are you serious? Please answer all my questions and remarks.

Comment: Please elaborate more as what you have to do. `How can I put the data of IMAGE_CONTENT_AS_BYTE_ARRAY`. You should ask that the one who gave you this task.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntity;

    String URL = "My server url";

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     Bitmap   bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, byteArrayOutputStream); 
        byte[] byteData = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

        ByteArrayBody byteArrayBody = new ByteArrayBody(byteData, "image"); // second parameter is the name of the image )

        // send the package
        multipartEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        multipartEntity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        multipartEntity.addPart("image", byteArrayBody);
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged in SO.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But in my case I dont have the kep as you have here "image"  I have simple restapi place holders http://my.domain.com/Upload/{ID}/{IMAGE_CONTENT_AS_BYTE_ARRAY}

Answer (score 0):

The best way to upload images or files is using multi part data format.
Here is a sample code for uploading image.

```
public static void postMultiPart(String url, File image) 
{
    final android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient client = android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("sample");
    // enable redirects
    HttpClientParams.setRedirecting(client.getParams(), true);

    final String encoded_url = encodeURL(url);
    final org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost post = new org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost(encoded_url);


    MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    mpEntity.addPart("profile", new FileBody(image));
    post.setEntity(mpEntity);

    org.apache.http.HttpResponse response;
    try {
        response = client.execute(post);
        final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (!(statusCode == org.apache.http.HttpStatus.SC_OK || statusCode == org.apache.http.HttpStatus.SC_CREATED)) {
            Log.i("Error:","Check....."+"Error " + statusCode + " while posting data to " + encoded_url + "\nreason phrase: " + response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());

            return;
        }

         Log.i("SUCCESS:","Check....."+Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));

    } catch (IOException e) {

    } finally {
        client.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But in my case I dont have the kep as you have here "profile" I have simple restapi place holders my.domain.com/Upload{ID}/{IMAGE_CONTENT_AS_BYTE_ARRAY}